# AWS Amplify: Change Auth Resource Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am using AWS amplify and have added authentication with

```
amplify add auth
```

When it asks for domain name prefix, I input test. However, the resource name becomes test34e61c5c. While this isn't a big deal, it is annoying since the folder and Cognito resource are also called test34e61c5c. Is there any way to guarantee there is no suffix id?